# My car won’t start and there’s water coming out of the muffler

Tags: starting

When I try to start my car doesn’t start and water comes out of the muffler I don’t know what’s going on with the car I don’t know if it’s a blown head gasket it or I have a leak in the coolant system please help

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is it water or is it coolant?

Comment: Hi Jacqueline - we will need more info. What is the liquid, can you describe its colour, smell etc

Comment: Have you had to top-up the coolant reservoir?

Comment: Touch the liquid then touch your tongue, glyco antifreeze will be sweet , spit and rinse. I am not saying to drink antifreeze ! I have done it several times any not died yet.

Comment: If the car isn't starting the liquid could actually be the unburnt fuel.